# Baby has dual citizenship. I need to know if she needs two passports

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, dual-nationality, mexico

I am traveling to the United States with my husband, Mexican, and our daughter, who is Mexican/American.

Do I need to get her a Mexican passport as well? She already has her American passport.

I do not want any issues leaving Mexico or coming back to Mexico if she is supposed to have both passports.

Comment: It is "madness" not to get all passports possible.  Go get the passport.

Comment: @Fattie What do you base that opinion on?

Answer (score 5):

You're **way** overthinking this. Mexican immigration **doesn't even require Mexican citizens to present a passport.**

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Passport Exemptions:
>
> Nationals of Mexico with a:
>
> - national ID card; or
> - certified copy of birth certificate; or
> - consular registration; or
> - certificate of Mexican nationality; or
> - naturalization letter; or
> - Matricula Consular; or
> - Constancia de Identificacion; or
> - voter's certificate with photo.

("national ID card" here refers to the *cédula de identitad personal*)

So any of these documents alone will be enough to board a flight to Mexico and to re-enter Mexico. With one of these, she has absolutely no need for a Mexican passport.

She will obviously need a US passport to fly to the US.

Comment: I would just add that, given the source, any of those documents will also be enough to *board a flight to* Mexico.  Since the child seems to live in Mexico, "returning" to the US seems not to be a concern.

Comment: The idea of travelling with **an infant** with no passport, is simply insanity.  Get the passport.

Comment: @Fattie Why's it insanity, if a birth certificate is clearly accepted?

Comment: Anything can happen. Ask a parent. They could be diverted somewhere, they might have to travel somewhere else - border "officials" have total fiat power, one of them could get uppity for any reason. We're talking about a near third-world country and the world's primary arbitrary, non-systematic country.  It's a non-starter. Do everything you can to protect the infant.

Comment: @Fattie A Mexican citizen cannot be denied entry to Mexico

Answer (score 3):

No, but it's probably a good idea.

She is an American citizen with, presumably valid, American passport therefore she can travel on that passport. However, entering Mexico with an American passport generally limits stay to 180 days.

Traveling with the Mexican passport alone will require a US visa.

I recommend traveling with the US passport, but carrying the Mexican passport (or other document such as birth certificate) so that on returning back to Mexico you can show she is also a Mexican citizen and thus not subject to the stay limit for non-citizens.

Comment: Yeah, she has her CRBA and American passport.  Now is she going to have problems when returning to Mexico on only an American passport?  Will she have to have an FMM card?

Comment: Okay, that was my concern.  Returning to Mexico.  We don't have much time to obtain a Mexican passport, I just came across the issue yesterday.  I am still learning the dual nationality stuff right now.

Comment: If the daughter is _actually_ a national of Mexico, I don't think entering Mexico on a US passport can possibly oblige her to leave after a particular period of time. If she has no proof of Mexican nationality at the border, her US passport may get stamped with notations that _purport_ to admit her for a limited period of time, but that will retroactively become a nullity when she does later produce such proof.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, but if she is flying back to Mexico, she will not be allowed to board if she doesn't have a return ticket to the US.

Comment: Our daughter was born here, so she has her birth certificates from Mexico, and  all that.  If we are not able to get her Mexican passport in time, then we will just take all her paperwork with us, so upon returning to Mexico they will see she is a Mexican national as well.  Her American passport shows she was born here in Mexico.

Comment: @Nicole Yes, that will work. A Mexican birth certificate along with her US passport will be fine.

Comment: We live in Mexico and are traveling to the US to visit my family.

Comment: @ventsyv  Hey thanks.  I appreciate it.  Im sweating bullets here thinking we will have problems

Comment: @ventsyv  Thanks, yeah, I think were just going to take the American passport along with ALL her paperwork, so theres no issues.  Thx again for your help.

Comment: If you think of it, after the trip, come back and add your own answer, based on the aggregate of your advice from the trip. You can answer your own question.